# copy files from FTP to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, ftp

> I need to copy files from FTP sever outside my cluster to Hadoop i.e 
>   HDFS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?  [FTP TO HDFS](http://hadoop101.blogspot.com/2011/12/ftp-to-hdfs.html#!/2011/12/ftp-to-hdfs.html) ... You can modify this code and change arguments for File to be FTP a agrs[0] and HDFS Paht to args[1]. and than run it as hadoop jar. hope this'll help...

Comment: can we use oozie to download files directly from ftp to hdfs.. Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at WebHDFS (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html) or HttpFS (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html)

The services need access to the Hadoop cluster, then you could expose the HttpFS port to a server with access to the FTP server.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

hadoop fs -get ftp://uid:password@server_url/file_path temp_file | hadoop fs -moveFromLocal tmp_file hadoop_path/dest_file

Comment: In Python I did this: `subprocess.run('hadoop fs -get ftp://uid:password@server_url/file_path tmp_file | hadoop fs -moveFromLocal tmp_file hadoop_path/dest_file', check=True, shell=True)`

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of using the pipe between `hadoop` commands here, rather than just running the commands "sequentially"?