# Airflow scheduler periodically complains no heartbeat

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Have problem where the airflow (v1.10.5) webserver will complain...

> The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was received 45 minutes ago.

But checking the scheduler daemon process (started via `airflow scheduler -D`) can see...

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ cat airflow-scheduler.pid
64186
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ ps -aux | grep 64186
airflow   64186  0.0  0.1 663340 67796 ?        S    15:03   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow scheduler -D
airflow   94305  0.0  0.0 112716   964 pts/4    R+   16:01   0:00 grep --color=auto 64186
```

and after some period of time the error message *goes away again*).

This happens very frequently off-and-on even after restarting both the webserver and scheduler.

The `airflow-scheduler.err` file is empty and the .out and .log files appear innocuous (need more time to look through deeper).

Running the scheduler in the terminal to see the feed live, everything seems to run fine until I see this output in the middle of the dag execution

```sh
[2019-11-29 15:51:57,825] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-11-29 15:51:58,259] {dagbag.py:90} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/airflow/dags/my_dag_file.py
```

Once this pops up, I can see in the web UI that the scheduler heartbeat error message appears. (Oddly, killing the scheduler process here does not generate the heartbeat error message in the web UI). Checking for the scheduler process, I see...

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ ps -aux | grep scheduler
airflow    3409  0.2  0.1 523336 67384 ?        S    Oct24 115:06 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
airflow   25569  0.0  0.0 112716   968 pts/4    S+   16:00   0:00 grep --color=auto scheduler
airflow   56771  0.0  0.1 662560 67264 ?        S    Nov26   4:09 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
airflow   64187  0.0  0.1 662564 67096 ?        S    Nov27   0:00 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
airflow  153959  0.1  0.1 662568 67232 ?        S    15:01   0:06 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
```

IDK if this is this normal or not.

Anyone know what could be going on here or how to fix?

---

*UPDATE*:

Thought the problem may have been that there were older scheduler processes that were not deleted that were still running...

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ kill -9 3409 36771
bash: kill: (36771) - No such process
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ ps -aux | grep scheduler
airflow   56771  0.0  0.1 662560 67264 ?        S    Nov26   4:09 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
airflow   64187  0.0  0.1 662564 67096 ?        S    Nov27   0:00 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
airflow  153959  0.0  0.1 662568 67232 ?        S    Nov29   0:06 airflow scheduler -- DagFileProcessorManager
airflow  155741  0.0  0.0 112712   968 pts/2    R+   15:54   0:00 grep --color=auto scheduler
```

Notice all the various start times in the output.

Doing a `kill -9 56771 64187 ...` and then rerunning `airflow scheduler -D` does not seem to have fixed the problem.

Note: the scheduler seems to consistently stop running after a task fails to move a file from an FTP location to an HDFS one...

```sh
hadoop fs -Dfs.mapr.trace=debug -get \
        ftp://$FTP_CLIENT:$FTP_PASS@$FTP_IP/$FTP_DIR"$TABLENAME.TSV" \
        $PROJECT_HOME/tmp/"$TABLENAME.TSV"
# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46433847/8236733
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have found the problem. 
Had a piece of code like...

```sh
hadoop fs -Dfs.mapr.trace=debug -get \
        ftp://$FTP_CLIENT:$FTP_PASS@$FTP_IP/$FTP_DIR"$TABLENAME.TSV" \
        $PROJECT_HOME/tmp/"$TABLENAME.TSV" \
        | hadoop fs -moveFromLocal $PROJECT_HOME/tmp/"$TABLENAME.TSV" "$DATASTORE"
```

changed to

```sh
hadoop fs -Dfs.mapr.trace=debug -get \
        ftp://$FTP_CLIENT:$FTP_PASS@$FTP_IP/$FTP_DIR"$TABLENAME.TSV" \
        $PROJECT_HOME/tmp/"$TABLENAME.TSV"
hadoop fs -moveFromLocal $PROJECT_HOME/tmp/"$TABLENAME.TSV" "$DATASTORE"
```

IDK why, but there seems to have been a problem with using the pipe in this way, not sure why, but I *suspect* that it has something to do with latency issues when having to read from the local temp dir before writing to `-moveFromLocal` (because would get similar 'file not found' errors when running the commands manually in the shell when chained together with a pipe).

Also not sure why any of this would cause the airflow scheduler to have problems, but have run the task several times now since the change and have not seen the scheduler error again, so not sure what to make of that.

If anyone can explain any of this weirdness please do let me know to make this answer a bit more complete. Will continue to debug and update.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I started the webserver with a different `AIRFLOW_HOME` than the scheduler. Make sure that the webserver and the scheduler use the same Airflow home directory, for example, by running

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME='/path/to/the/airflow_home'
```

before running the webserver and scheduler.

Comment: Had tried that but still loses heartbeat. In the only dag I have tested with, it seems to happen whenever a dag task fails (which is odd since it is not even related to the scheduler as i can see (I made an intentional file permission access error for testing)).